# How do I get separate buttons to run the same function for their respective rows?

Tags: javascript, html

https://jsfiddle.net/50kyg2yt/

```
<script>
        function change() {
                var elem = document.getElementById("out");
                if (elem.value=="OUT") elem.value = "IN";
                else elem.value = "OUT";
            }
        function color() {
                var background = document.getElementById("out").style.backgroundColor;
                if (background == "rgb(26, 255, 0)") {
                    document.getElementById("out").style.background = "rgb(255,0,0)";
                } 
                else {
                    document.getElementById("out").style.background = "rgb(26,255,0)";
                }

            }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <table id="board" style="width:100%">
        <tr id="head">
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Out</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row1">
            <td id="name">
                Row 1
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <input onclick="change(); color()" type="button" value="OUT" id="out" style="background-color: red"></input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row2">
                <td id="name">
                    Row 2
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input onclick="change(); color()" type="button" value="OUT" id="out" style="background-color: red"></input>
                </td>
        </tr>
```

I have a table that will eventually have multiple rows.  When a button in row 1 is clicked, it changes color from red to green and from out to in.

Then on if I click the row 2 button, it changes the row 1 button.  But I want it to change the row 2 button.

I am very very new to this and trying to teach myself so is there a simpler way of doing this without copying the code and changing the ids and everything?

Thanks for any help!

And I apologize for the abomination that is my code in the html window on fiddle.

M

Comment: Welcome to SO Mark. I would recommend you go through some html/css tutorials and courses online to get a better grasp of how they work (for example, like how you cant use the same 'id' on more than one element, etc.) Also, do provide a valid reason when you downvote answers here in SO. Cheers.

Comment: `id` must be unique. You can use data-attributes instead, like `data-id` and then use `row.querySelector("data-id")` to get the element (`row` is the element of the `tr`)

Comment: Here is a suggested blog post for you @AndreiGheorghiu : https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: @AndrewL - Thanks, will do.  I've been doing some reading but just getting my feet wet.

Comment: Sweet man. Cheers!

Comment: @some, I asked a legitimate question, since there has been **zero** research effort. When asking here one assumes a developer status. Developers (re)search. [A lot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @some, perhaps you should read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858/) and [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366665/). As for what I personally think... Well, [SO] is not a welcoming committee. It's a tool and it should be sharp, as it used to be. We shouldn't allow it to be blunted by garbage. It's becoming less useful every day because everyone thinks it's OK to ask without research, because it's become much harder to find a useful answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of always referencing the same element (`document.getElementById`) inside `change` and `color` functions, pass the reference of your elements to these functions.

So basically something like this :

```
function change(elem) {
    if (elem.value=="OUT") 
        elem.value = "IN";
    else 
        elem.value = "OUT";
}

function color(elem) {
    var background = elem.style.backgroundColor;
    if (background == "rgb(26, 255, 0)") {
        elem.style.background = "rgb(255,0,0)";
    } 
    else {
        elem.style.background = "rgb(26,255,0)";
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n2b1k53j/

Comment: Thats what I needed!  Now to read this through and figure out what exactly does what.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

For starters, `id` is supposed to be unique on the page. Use classes in such cases.

- Bind events using JS and avoid inline event handlers.
- Use `this` in cases when you want to reference the element that invoked the event handler.
- Use classes to change the styling instead of inline styles.

```js
// select all the elements with a speicific class
// and iterate over using forEach
document.querySelectorAll('.out').forEach(function(elem) {
  // bind a click event for each element in iteration
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // toggle the value and background based on the active class
    if (this.classList.contains('active')) {
      this.classList.remove('active');
      this.value = "OUT";
    } else {
      this.classList.add('active');
      this.value = "IN";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.out {
  background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

.active {
  background: rgb(26,255,0);
}
```

```html
<table id="board" style="width:100%">
  <tr id="head">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Out</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="name">
      Row 1
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="button" value="OUT" class="out" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td id="name">
      Row 2
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input type="button" value="OUT" id="out" class="out" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table
```

Answer (score -2):

using events you can do your trick.

working example:

```js
function change(e) {
  var elem = e.target;
  elem.value = (elem.value == "OUT")?"IN":"OUT";
}

function color(e) {
  var background = e.target.style.backgroundColor;
  e.target.style.background = (background == "rgb(26, 255, 0)")?"rgb(255,0,0)":"rgb(26,255,0)";
}
```

```html
<table id="board" style="width:100%">
  <tr id="head">
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Out</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="name">
      Row 1
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input onclick="change(event); color(event)" type="button" value="OUT" id="out" style="background-color: red"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td id="name">
      Row 2
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <input onclick="change(event); color(event)" type="button" value="OUT" id="out" style="background-color: red"></input>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```